# How to remove linux mint useless login screen?

Tags: linux-mint, screen-lock, settings

I've managed to remove password on login but can't remove this useless screen, so every time I boot up I have to press the "Log in" button to bypass it:

[image: Login screen on Mint 19]

Following on from a comment suggestion I've tried the solutions listed at [How do I enable auto-login in Mint 18?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381785/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-mint-18)  but nothing has changed.
I edited `lightdm.conf` file to include `autologin-enable=true` which wasn't there, and nothing has changed

Perhaps it's because I'm running Linux Mint 19 Tara, Cinnamon 3.8.7 whereas the suggested duplicate is for Mint 18. I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried setting up autologin?

Comment: I don't have the "automatic login" option, instead, I have "manual login" one, and it's already turned off

Comment: Linux Mint 19 Tara, Cinnamon 3.8.7

Comment: If the Mint 18 fix doesn't work for you, please would you [update your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/472446/edit) to show exactly what you added, and to which file. Then what did you do? Thanks.